# How to restart persistent volume state

Tags: kubernetes, ceph

I have a kubernetes running a gitlab, redis and postgress in a ceph persistent volume.

Today the gitlab pod was reset and it failed to mount the PVC.

Then I've deteled all persistentVolumeClaim related but it still in `Failed` state I seems to be blocking new `PVC` to init.

```
kubectl get pv 
NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   RECLAIMPOLICY   STATUS    CLAIM                         STORAGECLASS   REASON    AGE
pvc-114be463-0e5a-11e7-84d4-005056b3448a   20Gi       RWO           Retain          Bound     default/kube-registry-pvc     slow                     112d
pvc-38d0f0e1-2b93-11e7-bc8d-005056b3448a   100Gi      RWO           Retain          Failed    default/jenkins-pvc           slow                     75d
pvc-6207061a-0e5a-11e7-84d4-005056b3448a   50Gi       RWO           Retain          Failed    default/gitlab-pvc            slow                     112d
pvc-62ff778c-0e5a-11e7-84d4-005056b3448a   50Gi       RWO           Retain          Failed    default/gitlab-postgres-pvc   slow                     112d
pvc-63f8dcd5-0e5a-11e7-84d4-005056b3448a   50Gi       RWO           Retain          Failed    default/gitlab-redis-pvc      slow                     112d
```

How can I reset the PV status ? 
Or Is possible to fix PV Status ?

Answer (score 1):

You may have to delete and recreate the PersistentVolume resource.